# If Vivaldi is using Chromium (Chrome's engine), why do various things still not work?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium, web, vivaldi

After painfully switching from Firefox a few years ago, when Mozilla finally nailed the last nail into the privacy and user-respecting coffin, I carefully went through every single web browser and rejected them one by one, eventually being *forced* to unhappily settle for Vivaldi, simply because it uses Chrome's engine and is made by the old Opera people, so there is some minimal sense of usability in certain aspects.

But now I sit here and experience how webpage after webpage **still** is broken in ridiculous ways. Nothing happens when I press menu items, or no content is shown at all between the menu and footer, etc. Things that happened while using Firefox/Pale Moon/whatever. Things which I assumed were the result of everyone only knowing or caring about Google Chrome.

But now I basically run Google Chrome, rendering engine-wise. And yet things don't work. How can this possibly be explained?

Comment: Have you compared to running actual Chrome. Have you removed any extensions you may have added. Have you tested from a different computer, &/or network?

Comment: The problem might be not with the rendering, but with the JaveScript engine's compatibility.

Comment: @harrymc But the JavaScript engine is also taken from Chromium?

Comment: @Tetsujin I can't install Google Chrome for obvious security and privacy reasons, but if the sites are even broken in Chrome, well... that would be very strange.

Comment: If you can't a/b test, there's not much else we can say. Chrome is not Chromium, they merely have the same base code.

Comment: What @Tetsujin said. Without you defining what "various things" are broken, how is anyone meant to give a useful answer to this question?

Comment: Have you tried Vivaldi's own troubleshooting suggestions https://help.vivaldi.com/desktop/troubleshoot/troubleshooting-issues/?

Comment: Please provide a concrete example of a page that is broken and describe how it is broken.